# LEFT JOIN without LIMIT existing in query

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I've the following tables:

**poll**:

```
id | question   | votes
1  | Your name? | 2
```

**poll_answers**:

```
id | id_poll | answer
1  | 1       | John
2  | 1       | Jorge
3  | 1       | Charlie
```

And I want to do a `SELECT` to return the `poll` data and the `poll_answers` data with the `id_poll` corresponding to `id` on `poll` table.

So, I did:

```
SELECT question, votes, answer
FROM poll
LEFT JOIN poll_answers
ON poll.id = id_poll
WHERE poll.id = '1'
LIMIT 1
```

And the expected output would be return the `poll` data and the three answers on `poll_answers` table, but, the output is:

> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["question"]=> string(10) "Your name?"
>   ["votes"]=> string(1) "2" ["answer"]=> string(5) "Charlie" } }

What I want:

> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["question"]=> string(10) "Your name?"
>   ["votes"]=> string(1) "2" ["answer"]=> string(7) "Charlie" ["answer"]=>
>   string(5) "Jorge" ["answer"]=> string(4) "John" } }

How to do this, using `LIMIT` on the main query but without `LIMIT` on the `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with a *limit on the main query*; Using `WHERE poll.id = '1'` you are already limiting the number of results from the `poll` table to 1. So you don't need a `LIMIT` at all as far as I can tell.

Comment: I edited my question, and I understand their thinking, but, using `LIMIT` we don't have more performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT p.question, p.votes, GROUP_CONCAT(pa.answer) as answer
FROM poll p LEFT JOIN
     poll_answers pa
     ON p.id = pa.id_poll
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```